# Como Atualizar só Alguns Campos Put em SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8

Olá Pessoal Explicando rapidamento o codigo esse endpoint ai é minha rota que atualiza um aluno já cadastrado eu entro com os dados que quero cadastrar e manda pra função atualizar e la "Seta" os dados o grande problema é que isso só funciona se eu "Setar" tudo, porque se eu deixa algum campo vazio, isso registra no banco de dados como null, tentei fazer uma condicional para ver se as variaveis estão nulas ou não porém quando entra na condicional das strings, como "nome" e "senha" da execption, Enfim a pergunta é : Como alterar só alguns campos no Put sem acabar setando nulo nos outros?, sem criar outras funcões pra isso, porque ai só tem 4 atributos, imagine se tivesse 40 e tivessemos que fazer uma função cada combinação de atributos usados.

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
@Transactional
public ResponseEntity<AlunoDto> atualizar(@PathVariable Long id,@RequestBody AttAlunoForm form) {
        Aluno aluno = form.atualizar(id, alunosRepository);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new AlunoDto(aluno));
}
```

```
    public Aluno atualizar(Long id, AlunosRepository alunosRepository) {
        Aluno aluno = alunosRepository.getOne(id);
            aluno.setIdade(idade);
            aluno.setNome(nome);
            aluno.setSenha(senha);
            aluno.setRenda(renda);
    
        return aluno;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

No caso de atualização parcial do recurso deverá ser utilizado o método PATCH ao invés do PUT.

No caso do PUT deverá ser encaminhado a representação completa do recurso que está sendo atualizado.

[Put vs Patch - Medium](https://medium.com/@gabrielrufinoo/put-vs-patch-pare-de-agora-escolher-errado-533b8c6058d9)

Para o caso do PATCH onde há a necessidade de atualizar somente os atributos que foram encaminhados você pode utilizar um if para obter esse comportamento.

```
    public Aluno atualizar(Long id, AlunosRepository alunosRepository) {
        Aluno aluno = alunosRepository.getOne(id);
        if(idade != null) aluno.setIdade(idade);
        if(nome != null) aluno.setNome(nome);
        if(senha != null) aluno.setSenha(senha);
        if(renda != null) aluno.setRenda(renda);
    
        return aluno;
    }
```

Comment: pow mano mas é isso que eu digo, e se fosse 40 campos, ia setar os 40 ?